# TabLayout removes all tabs when PagerAdapter invoke notifyDataSetChanged() override TabLayout class and Exception

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I used to use text as title in TabLayout, but I decide to change to icon, at `onCreateView` use `tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic)`. But When I update my data set in PagerArray by notifyDataSetChanged() all tabs become empty. I found: [Issue 202402](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202402)

They writing the solution is create new Class extends TabLayout. So I did it:

```
public class SuperTabLayout extends TabLayout {
public SuperTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void addTab(Tab tab, boolean setSelected) {
    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_assessment_24dp);
    super.addTab(tab, setSelected);
}
```

}

And they writing so that don't forget about layout

```
    <com.paragraf.workhours.SuperTabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tablay1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivPersonAvatar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    class="com.paragraf.workhours.SuperTabLayout"
   />
```

But I got something like this:

```
10-17 21:07:18.600 28964-28964/com.paragrafxv.workhours E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.paragrafxv.workhours, PID: 28964
                                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.paragrafxv.workhours.SuperTabLayout
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                          at com.paragrafxv.workhours.SitePersonFragment.onCreateView(SitePersonFragment.java:86)
                                                                          at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.paragrafxv.workhours.SuperTabLayout
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:628)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at com.paragrafxv.workhours.SitePersonFragment.onCreateView(SitePersonFragment.java:86) 
                                                                          at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:592)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at com.paragrafxv.workhours.SitePersonFragment.onCreateView(SitePersonFragment.java:86) 
                                                                          at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Somebody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement all of the parent class' constructors. Specifically:

- [TabLayout(Context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#TabLayout(android.content.Context)) (used when manually creating)
- [TabLayout(Context, AttributeSet)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#TabLayout(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet)) (used when inflating from XML)
- [TabLayout(Context, AttributeSet, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#TabLayout(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int)) (used when inflating from XML with a style attribute)

As you don't declare the second one, your `SuperTabLayout` cannot be used from XML.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't know if I extends classes I have to use all constructors. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you intentionally calling `super.addTab(tab, setSelected)` after calling `tab.setIcon()`? That may be the issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is correct. For custom views you need at least a constructor that takes a `Context` and one that takes `Context` and `AttributeSet`

Comment: Read last post of issue